# Is there a solution to set user birthday to null, empty or default value?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I have set a birthday to a user.
I need to remove this birthday, but i'm unable.

I have tried PATCH method in the documentation but field cannot be null.
Then i have tried multiple calls with PATCH / PUT / DELETE but i always have an error.

In Delve when we delete the birthday, it becomes `'0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'`.
I have tried to PATCH the birthday with this value, but i get Unknow Error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",
        "message": "Unknown Error",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "678fbda6-5fb9-4bc0-91c3-7af2238c1673",
            "date": "2018-05-28T09:16:20"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can actually set the birthday to null,
as DateTimeOffset or any other structs aren't nullable in C#.
Thus when deleting birthday instead of null it will be set to the default value of the struct (which is '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z' for DateTimeOffset)

Comment: @KarlheinzReinhardt, i found no way to delete a user prop. Delete verb seems to be only allowed on /users/:id endpoint (not /users/:id/birthday)

Comment: Sorry, yes you cannot delete the a user property. With "delete birthday" i meant setting it to null.

Comment: tried to patch the birtday with some random dates. I noticed that every date below the year 1753 seems to fail.

Comment: I think the reason is that the Date is parsed on the ServerSide into a SqlDateTime which has a minimum date restriction of January 1, 1753 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the SharePoint REST API below to set the birthday of the user profile.

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/SetSingleValueProfileProperty
```

Example code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {   
    var requestHeaders = {
        'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    };

    var userData = {
        'accountName': "i:0#.f|membership|user@lz.onmicrosoft.com",
        'propertyName': 'SPS-Birthday', //can also be used to set custom single value profile properties
        'propertyValue': ''//set empty value
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/SetSingleValueProfileProperty",
        type: "POST",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqxr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note**: Modify the '**accountName**' in the code above and add the code into a script editor web part in the SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to delete the value at Birthday field and used that in PowerShell for creating (POST) and updating (PATCH) contacts. Hope, that helps :)

```
$ContactBirthday = @"
    "birthday": "$($UserBirthday)"
"@

$ContactNoBirthday = @"
    "birthday": null
"@

##MAIN##

##Get Graph Token
$Token = GetGraphToken -ClientSecret $ClientSecret -ClientID $ClientID -TenantID $TenantID

##ProcessImports

# If Birthday exists...
if ($UserBirthday){
    $ContactObject = '{' + $ContactBirthday + ', ' + $ContactObject + '}'
}
else{
    $ContactObject = '{' + $ContactNoBirthday + ', ' + $ContactObject + '}'
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33983130)